# Selecting just the stats in this data scrape in Python3

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.5

I'm trying to scrape data from this link: http://www.hoopsstats.com/basketball/fantasy/nba/opponentstats/16/12/eff/1-1

My goal is to be able to import this data into excel.

I've gotten this far in the code:

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.hoopsstats.com/basketball/fantasy/nba/opponentstats/16/12/eff/1-1')


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

stats = soup.find_all('table', 'statscontent')


print(stats)
```

here is the start of what's returned:

```
[<table bgcolor="#EBE9E9" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="statscontent" height="20" width="100%">
<tr id="myid1/0" onmouseout="hide_table_effect('myid1/0')" onmouseover="show_table_effect('myid1/0')">
<td width="3%"><center>1</center></td>
<td align="left" width="9%"><a href="/basketball/fantasy/nba/boston-celtics/team/profile/16/2">Boston</a></td>
<td width="3%"><center>66</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>48.0</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>19.6</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>5.2</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>7.2</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>1.8</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>0.5</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>4.3</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>4.1</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>4.3</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>0.9</center></td>
<td width="8%"><center>6.8-16.2</center></td>
<td width="3%"><center>.423</center></td>
<td width="7%"><center>1.6-5.0</center></td>
<td width="3%"><center>.324</center></td>
<td width="8%"><center>4.3-5.3</center></td>
<td width="3%"><center>.818</center></td>
<td width="5%"><center>19.8</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>-6.7</center></td>
</tr>
</table>, <table bgcolor="#F8F8F8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="statscontent" height="20" width="100%">
<tr id="myid1/1" onmouseout="hide_table_effect('myid1/1')" onmouseover="show_table_effect('myid1/1')">
<td width="3%"><center>2</center></td>
<td align="left" width="9%"><a href="/basketball/fantasy/nba/san-antonio-spurs/team/profile/16/27">San Antonio</a></td>
<td width="3%"><center>66</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>47.9</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>19.6</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>5.0</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>8.7</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>1.8</center></td>
<td width="4%"><center>0.3</center></td>
```

I need the numbers between 'x'

also preferably the data would be formatted so it could easily be used in CSV file

Comment: Can you show some more code of what you have done with `stats` ? -- it seems that you get the correct HTML, so now you need to parse that...

Comment: Sadly i'm pretty lost past this, just started with Python a couple days ago.  Any recommendations on tutorials with data parsing?  So far nothing has been too helpful and in general been very vague.

Comment: while it is more with presidents than with basketballs, you will love this here: http://programminghistorian.org/lessons/intro-to-beautiful-soup ...

Comment: i'll definately check that out

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to do the trick:

```
  import sys
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    r = requests.get('http://www.hoopsstats.com/basketball/fantasy/nba/opponentstats/16/12/eff/1-1')


    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    stats = soup.find_all('table', 'statscontent')


    for table in soup.find_all('table', 'statscontent','a'):
        stats = [ stat.text for stat in table.find_all('center') ]
        team = [team.text for team in table.find_all('a')]


        print(team,stats)
```

likely redundant or otherwise flawed, but I got what I wanted out of it